# Sweetalert confirm fails on form submit

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I am using the following code in html

```
<form name = "RegForm" id = "RegForm" class="form-horizontal" method= "post" onsubmit = "return SveFrm();" action = "action.php">
```

In the function, I am checking for errors and when found, I issue an alert:

```
function SveFrm(){
....
     if (err > 0){
        swal({ title: "Warning!",   
        text: "Some entries are missing.\nDo you still want to save this?",   
        type: "warning",   
        showCancelButton: true,   
        confirmButtonColor: "#5cb85c",   
        confirmButtonText: "Yes!",   
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel!",   
        closeOnConfirm: true,   
        closeOnCancel: true }, 
        function(isConfirm){   
            if (isConfirm) { 
                return true; 
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation(); 
                return false;
             } 
        });
     }
}
```

When the error is encountered, the alert flashes for a second and then the form is submitted automatically without waiting for any user input. There are no other catchable errors in my code. Clearly, something is wrong with my codes. Please help me correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these codes lines you can't use it, there is no reference to the `event` in you're function

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

stop the default action of submitting the form

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); SveFrm();">
```

if everything is ok submit the form

```
 if (isConfirm) { 
              document.forms['RegForm'].submit();
            }
```